# Load data with Core Data in UICollectionView before animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-data, swift3

I am pretty new to iOS development, but I could not find an answer to this question (maybe I could not find the right keywords to search..?).

Anyway, I have this "problem":

I have 2 storyboards, A and B, both with some views inside.
I go from view A-2 to view B-1 via @IBAction - a simple button click - with the following code:

```
 @IBAction func onExercisesButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Exercises", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExercisesVC") as UIViewController

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)    
}
```

On the other hand, in the B-1 view I have a UICollectionView that is populated with data coming from a CoreData model.
The cells within the UICollectionView appear only after the animation is completed. If I set animated: false in the perform function and thus no animation is performed from A-2 view to B-1 view the cells are immediately visible.

The cells are the only element that appear after the completion of the animation. What is the cause of this behaviour? Can I avoid it with some sort of preloading/prefetching or other methods?

**Is there a way to display the cells before the animation starts, just like the UICollectionView background and all the other elements within the view?**

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: doesn't your `CollectionViewCells` appear in both cases whether the presentation is animate or not? And where are you fetching the data from `CoreData` model?

Comment: Sure, it appears in both cases BUT if the presentation is not animated it appears immediately, while if it's animated it waits for the end of the animation to show the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your view in `viewWillAppear:`.